# Change the value sent to variable in class A from AppDelegate in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

****What I am trying to do:****

I am attempting to increment the value of [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount by 1 for every second that passes. I have done this successfully. The problem is that I cannot call the following from within AppDelegate#timerCalled. How would I accomplish this?

```
_regularBubLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount];
```

## AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RWGameData.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

-(void)timerCalled;

@end
```

## AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

-(void)timerCalled
{
    NSLog(@"Timer Called");
    [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount++;
    NSLog(@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount);
    [[RWGameData sharedGameData] save];

}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerCalled) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

## PrimaryViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RWGameData.h"

@interface PrimaryViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *regularBubLabel;

@end
```

## PrimaryViewController.m

```
#import "PrimaryViewController.h"

@interface PrimaryViewController ()

@end

@implementation PrimaryViewController
{
    NSString *bubbleImage;
    int r;
    int i;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _regularBubLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount];
    _premiumBubLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].premiumBubbleCount];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)increment {
    if ([@"mysterybubble.png" isEqual:bubbleImage]) {
        [RWGameData sharedGameData].premiumBubbleCount += 2;
        _premiumBubLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].premiumBubbleCount];
    } else if ([@"megaBubbleLarge30.png" isEqual:bubbleImage]) {
        [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount += 50000;
        _regularBubLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount];
    } i++;
}

- (IBAction)save {
    [[RWGameData sharedGameData] save];
}

- (IBAction)setBubbleStatus {
    r = arc4random_uniform(300);

    if (r <= 12) {
        bubbleImage = @"mysterybubble.png";
        [_megaBubbleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:bubbleImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"Roll SUCCESS. [%i] %i", i, r);
    } else {
        bubbleImage = @"megaBubbleLarge30.png";
        [_megaBubbleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:bubbleImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"Roll FAIL. [%i] %i", i, r);
    }

}

@end
```

## RWGameData.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RWGameData : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (assign, nonatomic) long regularBubbleCount;

+(instancetype)sharedGameData;
-(void)reset;
-(void)save;

@end
```

## RWGameData.m

```
#import "RWGameData.h"

@implementation RWGameData

static NSString* const SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey = @"regularBubbleCount";

+ (instancetype)sharedGameData {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [self loadInstance];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)reset {
    self.regularBubbleCount = 0;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.regularBubbleCount forKey: SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _regularBubbleCount = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey];
    }
    return self;
}

+(NSString*)filePath
{
    static NSString* filePath = nil;
    if (!filePath) {
        filePath =
        [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]
         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gamedata"];
    }
    return filePath;
}

+(instancetype)loadInstance
{
    NSData* decodedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [RWGameData filePath]];
    if (decodedData) {
        RWGameData* gameData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodedData];
        return gameData;
    }

    return [[RWGameData alloc] init];
}

-(void)save
{
    NSData* encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self];
    [encodedData writeToFile:[RWGameData filePath] atomically:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: Please extract just the relevant code, and add a statement about what or doesn't happen with the current code and what you have done to troubleshoot. Where are you stumped? As near as I can see from this, the only real result of the timer firing is the call to `[[RWGameData sharedGameData] save];` and you did not provide any code from RWGameData so I don't know what that does. I don't see any code that calls anything from the view controller...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a response, @RobP. I have gone ahead and updated the post by removing some of the irrelevant code and adding in the RWGameData header file. I have also revised what I am trying to do so that it is more easily understood.

Comment: Where is RWGameData.m it all about it!

Answer (score 0):

Either you need the timer to invoke a selector on the PrimaryViewController instead of the AppDelegate, or else the AppDelegate needs to store a reference to the PrimaryViewController in order to call a method on the View Controller that updates the label.

A third (less recommended) method is to send out an NSNotification when the timer fires and have multiple VC's observe and respond to the notification, but that's harder to debug later.

You didn't show the code where the instance of PrimaryViewController gets created, but normally you'd store the reference in a property so you can access it later.

If there are many such view controllers, then the code which creates the ViewControllers (is this the AppDelegate?) should have a property which is an NSMutableArray of view controllers, say `myTimerViewControllers`. When the timer fires, inside `timerCalled`, iterate through them and tell each one to update its label.

To really do this with the best pattern, you'd create a simple @protocol with one method (say, `handleTimer` or `updateTimerLabel`). Each of the VC's would be declared as supporting this protocol, and the AppDelegate would have code something like:

```
for(UIViewController<TimerProtocol> *vc in myTimerViewControllers) {
    [vc handleTimer];
}
```

Comment: Again, thank you for your answer. Which of the two methods would you recommend? I have several ViewControllers which will need to display this change, so perhaps that's something to take into consideration. And from a programming standpoint, how would I accomplish the method of choice? I apologize; I'm new to this so I am trying to learn as much as I can.

Comment: I am honestly not sure what creates the View Controllers. At first guess, I would assume that would be 'Main.Storyboard' but after looking further into it I believe it could be 'main.m'? I haven't been able to figure out how to store a reference to the ViewControllers just yet, but I will keep looking.